# Убрать зазор между "subplots" или несколько областей рисования

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как убрать расстояние у графиков или сделать несколько областей для построения графиков справа и слева?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

ax[0].plot(range(10), 'r')
ax[1].plot(range(10), 'g')
ax[1].tick_params(labelleft='off',left=False)

plt.show()
```

Чтобы они были вместе друг с другом, как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в конце (перед `plt.show()`) использовать:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за subplots_adjust. Реально помогло!